# DateTime.TryParse without Culture

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, .net-core

I want to check whether date is valid to parse. But when i tried with below logic, it is falling for the valid date (eg: ‎3‎/‎10‎/‎2020).
I am receiving this myDate via ajax request.

I tried by changing culture, but still, it didn't work

```
DateTime validMyDate;
if(DateTime.TryParse(myDate, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out validMyDate)){}
```

Appriciate your kind help

**Edited:** Please find the ajax code at here

```
//fileds

<input name="StartDate" id="StartDate" type="hidden" value="3/10/2020 12:00:00 AM"  data-val="true">
<input name="EndDate" id="EndDate" type="hidden" value="3/26/2020 12:00:00 AM"  data-val="true">

// ajax call
$.get(domainUrl + "Controller/Action",
            {
              strartDate: dateFormatter.fomat($('#StartDate').val(), "mm/dd/yyyy"),
                endDate:  dateFormatter.fomat($('#EndDate').val(), "mm/dd/yyyy");
            },
            function (result) {

            }).fail(function (error) {

            });


// date formatter
var dateFormatter = {
    fomat: function (date, format) {
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth();
        var day = date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate();
        var newDate;
        switch (format) {
            case "dd/mm/yyyy": newDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                break;            
            default: newDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
        }
        return newDate;
    }
}
```

**Please note** : this format function is added, because `.val()` didn't work at the begging, so i format it again to check whether it is working.

Comment: You can use `TryParseExact` instead of `TryParse` to control the format.

Comment: i tried, this too
`DateTime.TryParseExact("‎3‎/‎10‎/‎2020","dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out validStartDate) 
//false
DateTime.TryParseExact("‎3‎/‎10‎/‎2020","dd/mm/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None, out validStartDate) 
//false`

Comment: `mm` stands for minutes, you need `MM`. Also, you have a single digit for day, so you should use `d/MM/yyyy` instead of `dd/MM/yyyy` - and if you're using a single digit for months until September (included) then you need `M` and not `MM`

Comment: Still same, I tried many ways as below

`DateTime.TryParseExact("‎3‎/‎10‎/‎2020","dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None, out validStartDate) 
//false
DateTime.TryParseExact("‎3‎/‎10‎/‎2020","MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out validStartDate) 
//false
DateTime.TryParseExact("‎3‎/‎10‎/‎2020","M/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None, out validStartDate) 
//false`

Comment: "I am receiving this myDate via ajax request" - are you able to change your AJAX code? I'd strongly encourage you to make sure that dates are transmitted in ISO-8601 format (yyyy-MM-dd).

Comment: But I suspect at least part of the reason this is failing is that your string includes U+200E five times. That's the left-to-right marker character, and really shouldn't be anywhere in your string.

Comment: if i by hard same date [], function is working fine `DateTime.TryParse(myDate,out validMyDate)`. 
If there is a way to remove this locale, i hope this would work. 

`DateTime.TryParseExact("‎3‎/‎10‎/‎2020","M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out validStartDate) 
//false
DateTime.TryParseExact("3/10/2020","M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out validStartDate) 
//true`

Comment: It's not a locale problem (although it's not a good idea to use MM/dd/yyyy as a data format IMO). It's a problem of extra invisible characters in your data.

Comment: I would *very strongly* advise you not to write your own date formatting code at all. Use something like MomentJS instead, and use ISO-8601 format in your JSON. It's not obvious to me where the rogue characters are coming from in your JSON, but writing your own date formatting code certainly isn't going to help that.

Comment: The code that needs fixing is the Javascript code. Why are there invisible characters to begin with? Why format the date on your own, why not use `Date.toISOString()` at least?

Comment: I'm not a javascript programmer, but I don't like your javascript one bit. If `month` is less than 10 it's a string, if it's higher it's an integer. The same goes for `day`. That makes my old programmer skin crawl.

Comment: Understood, I copied it for my testing, to figure out issue only. Thanks @PalleDue;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code definitely works:

```cs
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("3/10/2020","d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime validStartDate))
{
}
```

But there is something rotten with your string. If I copy "3/10/2020" from your comment above, it doesn't work. If I write it myself it works. Your string must be in some weird encoding, but I can't put my finger on what it is.

**EDIT:**
To remove the invisible characters do this:

```cs
var str = "‎3‎/‎10‎/‎2020";
str = str.Replace("\u200E","");
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str,"d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime validStartDate))
{
}
```

but it will be a hack. The problem should be changed at the other end.

Comment: It's that the OP's string includes [U+200E](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) five times.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Well, that explains it. How did you find out? Pasting into Notepad++ didn't reveal it.

Comment: I have a little tool here: https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Unicode#explorer

Comment: @JonSkeet; you are right. That the is the issue, i am having too
@PalleDue; do you any idea to remove that, because i can not remove this by hard cording it. I am receiving it from the front end via ajax call

Comment: @KosalaFernando: Then the problem is in the AJAX code, and we don't have any idea what that looks like.

Comment: @JonSkeet; I have update question with the ajax code, do you find issue at there

Comment: `DateTime.TryParseExact("‎3‎/‎10‎/‎2020".Replace("\u200E",""),"M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out validStartDate) `

Is working fine, 
Thanks  
@PalleDue;  & 
@JonSkeet;

Comment: No need of culture and all, just below code is working fine.

`DateTime.TryParse("‎3‎/‎10‎/‎2020".Replace("\u200E", ""), out validStartDate) `

Comment: I would strongly advise not just working around the problem without investigating further. It's likely to come up in other places. Work out *why* those characters are being sent, and fix that. This solution may be useful in the very short term if you've got an outage due to the problem, but I would make fixing the underlying cause a high priority.

Comment: Yes that is true @JonSkeet; For time been i am saved, I  only experience with this only Edge browser, It is working fine with crome. I working to find out the issue.